# Authentication issues when accessing localhost with ngrok

Tags: css, .net, iphone, auth0, ngrok

I'm trying to test how my css looks on an iphone (through browserstack), without having to deploy it to the test environment everytime I make changes. Choosing iphone views in Chrome dev tools shows my css working fine, hence the reason I'm using browserstack.

To achieve this, I'm accessing localhost using ngrok, however I'm encountering authentication issues with Auth0 - navigating to pages requiring authentication with the ngrok-generated URL redirects me to localhost:5000/callback instead of using the ngrok-generated URL.

The unhandled exception I'm encountering is:
System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
---> System.Exception: Correlation failed.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Apologies if I have not been specific enough. I also welcome alternative suggestions to achieve my original goal, which is to be able to successfully emulate the iphone view without deploying the application every time. Besides Chrome dev tools, I have tried a Chrome extension called "Mobile simulator - responsive testing tool".

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. OAuth protocol used by Auth0 works by redirecting you to the server with a code. Now in your development setup, the redirect URL is set as `localhost:5000/callback`.

1. You need to change it to `<ngrok_url>/callback`.
2. You also need to set this callback URL in Auth0 configuration under allowed redirect URLs.